# Excel VBA Ifelse statement

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a simple macro that with a cllick of a button will run the selected macro based on the parameter defined.

I have this cell setup on A2 with 1,2.

Basically, the logic of the code below works when A2 is value 1, it will run Macro 1 and if A2 is value 2 it will run macro 2.
However, when i run this script, it will always run Macro 2 regardless of what A2 value is.

I have researched and found my syntax for vba elseif is correct but i couldn't understand what went wrong. Can someone help me out?

```
Sub buttonclick()

Dim Num As Integer
Num1 = 1
Num2 = 2
' if Range("A2").Value = Num1 Then
    Call Macro1
' ElseIf Range("A2").Value = Num2 Then
    Call Macro2
' Else

' End If

End Sub



Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Sheets("Presentation_LO&Ev").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$K$151").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="A"

End Sub


Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Sheets("Presentation_LO&Ev").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$K$151").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="B"
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of button are you using? Where did you put your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted has all the If..Then...ElseIf logic commented out, so it will run Macro1 and immediately afterwards Macro2. Therefore it may look like only Macro2 has run.

If your actual code is different, step through the debugger and see what Range("A2").Value actually contains when it comes to do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of what you want to achieve.
I used `Form Control`

[image]

And put the code in a `Module`.

[image]

```
Sub MacroToBeAssignedOnTheButton()
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Replace with your actual sheet name
        If .Range("A1").Value2 = 1 Then Macro1 Else Macro2
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Macro1()
    MsgBox "Macro1 Ran" 'Replace with your actual code
End Sub

Private Sub Macro2()
    MsgBox "Macro2 Ran" 'Replace with your actual code
End Sub
```

Try putting your actual code in here and see if it works.

Comment: Ill try this code out too! Thanks for your help! Really Appreciate